# How to get the URL from the HTML code in an efficient way using PHP?

Tags: php, html, url, html-parsing

I've following two variables which contains the HTML code :

```
$var1= Profile photo uploaded<div class="comment_attach_image">
<a class="group1 cboxElement" 
   href="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" >
  <img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" height="150px" width="150px" />
</a>

<a class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" >Download</a>
</div>

$var2 = PDF file added<div class="comment_attach_file">
        <a class="comment_attach_file_link" href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf" >1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf</a>

        <a class="comment_attach_file_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf" >Download</a>
        </div>
```

I want to extract only the URL's from the above two variables. What I want from the above two variables is as follows :

```
$new_var1 = http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png;

$new_var2 = http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf ;
```

How to do this in an efficient and smarter way in PHP?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.  Are you saying you want to use PHP to extract URLs from HTML?

Comment: @Sildoreth:Yes, you got my point exactly but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me in this regard please?

Comment: You'll need to provide additional clarification.  How is the PHP being given the HTML to process?  What code do you have so far?

Comment: Regex is the solution!

Comment: @AmitThakur No, an HTML Parser is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Or do it the *PHP* way (yeah … j/k):

```
<?php

$var1 = 'Profile photo uploaded<div class="comment_attach_image">
<a class="group1 cboxElement" 
   href="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" >
  <img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" height="150px" width="150px" />
</a>

<a class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" >Download</a>
</div>';

$var2 = 'PDF file added<div class="comment_attach_file">
        <a class="comment_attach_file_link" href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf" >1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf</a>

        <a class="comment_attach_file_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf" >Download</a>
        </div>';

$url_regex = '/(href|src)="(.*?)"/';

preg_match_all($url_regex, $var1, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

preg_match_all($url_regex, $var2, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

will yield this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(86) "href="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png""
    [1]=>
    string(85) "src="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png""
    [2]=>
    string(100) "href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "href"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "src"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "href"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(79) "http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png"
    [1]=>
    string(79) "http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png"
    [2]=>
    string(93) "http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png"
  }
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(100) "href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf""
    [1]=>
    string(100) "href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "href"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "href"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(93) "http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(93) "http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf"
  }
}
```

See [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) for what's included. If you really only need the first URL that matches, go for [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), it has the same function signature as `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript would be a much better option if you're trying to parse a DOM. But, if you insist on using PHP, try downloading this HTML parser called [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). There is good documentation on their site, but for what you're trying to do, I'd use the following

```
// Get the contents of your page
$html = file_get_html('http://linkto.com/yourfile.html');

// Find all links this way
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)  {
   echo $element->href.'<br>';
}

// Target the two particular variables as follows
// Target the first variable by the anchor tag's class name
$new_var1 = $html->find('a[class=group1 cboxElement]', 0)->href; 
$new_var2 = $html->find('a[class=comment_attach_file_link_dwl]', 0)->href;
```